# using a resource inside a taglib definition in grails?

Tags: grails, taglib

I’m new to grails and I want to write a taglib but I can't figure out how to reference a resource inside the MyTagLib.groovy file.
The resource that I want retrieve the path is a picture. 
I tried something like what I used to do in the gsp file like this:

> < g:resource dir="images/icons/flag-icons/" file="gb.png" />

and this

> ${resource(dir: 'images/icons/flag-icons/', file: 'gb.png')}

But it doesn’t work

Comment: "it doesn't work" - in what way?  Do you get an exception (if so post the stack trace), simply no output at all, or output that is different from what you expect?  Can you show the whole tag definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taglibs are available from within other taglibs (and controllers) via a variable matching their namespace (the value of the `static namespace` field). In the case of Grails' built-in taglibs:

```
g.resource(dir: 'images/icons/flag-icons/', file: 'gb.png')
```